# Let view visible at scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view that contains

On top a header - view 1 
Under the header a radiogroup 
Under the radio grup a listview

At scrolling in list I want that radio grup to be visible all time in top 
If the user starts scrolling I don t want to see the view 1 , just scroll through list and see on top the radio group , if he scroll back to the top then I want to see view 1+ radiogroup + listview

Comment: you have to implement a scroll listener

Answer (score 1):

If your view1 is a header for your listview, you can check the function addHeaderView of a ListView, and add a custom xml view for that. This way, you will be able to scroll the view1 + listview, and have your radio group on top.

Look at that tutorial to implement a custom header :

http://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/